# where clause in sqlite is crashing my app when proguard is enabled

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android app that is using ORMlite library for accessing sqlite database. The scenario is as follows.

1. My app is working fine in debug mode i.e. without obfuscation.
2. When I enable proguard the app is crashing at the line where I used WHERE clause for accessing data from sqlite database.
3. If I remove WHERE clause part from the code the app is running fine even after obfuscation.

Please have a look on my proguard-project.txt and source code.

```
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

-keep class com.j256.** {
    *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-mergeinterfacesaggressively
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizationpasses 5

-verbose
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify


-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * extends android.app.Acitivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public interface com.google.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.adityabirla.firstresponse.database.ormlite.model.Contact

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}
```

Java Source File

```
    private void loadPersonalGrid() {
        try {
            Dao<Note, Integer> noteDao = ORMManager.getInstance(
                    getBaseContext()).getNoteDao();

            QueryBuilder<Note, Integer> queryBuilder = noteDao.queryBuilder();

//          queryBuilder.where().eq("category", Note.NOTE_CATEGORY_PERSONAL); // CRASHES WHEN ENABLED
            PreparedQuery<Note> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
            List<Note> noteList = noteDao.query(preparedQuery);
            NoteGridListAdapter adapter = new NoteGridListAdapter(this, noteList, NOTE_TYPE.PERSONAL, this);

            grid_personal.setAdapter(adapter);
            grid_personal.setExpanded(true);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the backtrace of the exception? You may use retrace.